# MongoDB querying issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How to query :

```
{
    "_id" : Object Id("58787242f7d06edbbb88f46e"),
    "name" : "aah",
    "values" : [ 
        "1484196300685", 
        "10"
    ],
    "attributes" : {

    }
}
```

**i need time where value=10**  result 1484196300685

Comment: Please show some effort. Did you actually try something yourself? This should be a basic query which is well-documented on the MongoDB website.

Comment: if you provided more detail of the results you're looking for it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find(
   { values: { $elemMatch: { $eq: "10" } } }
)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoveflow

Comment: if in this case how to use between ..   "values" : [ [ 
        "1484196300685", 
        "10"
    ],[ 
        "1484196300685", 
        "10"
    ]]

Comment: You can use $in

Comment: also to combine operation $and

Comment: please help me...I reached question limit .    how to take value between 10 and 50

{"values": [
[
1484626628446,
10,
3
],
[
1484626623207,
20,
3
],
[
1484626620587,
30,
3
],
[
1484626617967,
40,
3
],
[
1484626615347,
50,
3
]
}